# Show only username of user with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The title may not be very appropriate, so apologies in advance.

I'm building a rails app (not really experienced I'd say) and I used the [Amistad](https://github.com/raw1z/amistad) gem in order to add friendhsips. It has some cool features, like showing all friends. Unfortunately, I can't make it work as I wish.

I'm trying to show all users with pending request to the current user with:

```
Pending by: <%= current_user.pending_invited_by %>
```

But what I get as a result is

```
Pending by: [#<User avatar_url: nil, id: 16, username: "zxczxc", 
email: "zxczxc@zxczxc.zxc", created_at: "2011-10-01 16:50:24", 
updated_at: "2011-10-05 00:48:24", 
encrypted_password: "a80104b33a0183e096f2ec82b3b9a8c4240fe61828ef5030e52...", 
salt: nil, 
avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, 
avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>]
```

Is there a way to get only the username of the user, instead of the whole hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks more like an array of objects to me (not familiar with the gem you are using).

Does something like this work:

```
<% current_user.pending_invited_by.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.username %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
  <% current_user.pending_invited.each do |u| %>
    <%= u.username %> 
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Then I get an error message saying
 `undefined method 'username' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000481a840>`

Comment: Edited. It's an array, so you have to iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

From the Amistad docs it looks like evaluating `pending_invited_by` returns an array of users.  So you actually need to iterate over those to get the first name for each one.

```
Pending: <%= current_user.pending_invited_by.map{|user| user.username }.join(", ") %>
```

Comment: You're calling join on the string username now. ;) `current_user.pending_invited_by.map(&:username).to_sentence`

Comment: You could also do the same thing like this: `current_user.pending_invited_by.map(&:username).join(", ")`

Comment: @AshleyWilliams That's basically what `to_sentence` does, only it adds "and " after the penultimate item.

Comment: @coreyward I didn't actually notice your comment, and that somebody'd already mentioned the &:username method. Though, the #to_sentence version is nicer, I forgot about that!